# error of insufficient access when binding as the rootdn/rootpw

Tags: ldap, openldap

I was trying openldap step to step following its [quick-start-guide](http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/quickstart.html) on ubuntu 14,when I try to add slapd.ldif in this way:

```
ldapadd -x -D "cn=manager,dc=eg,dc=com" -w secret -f slapd.ldif.default
```

with my sldap.conf

```
include         /usr/local/etc/openldap/schema/core.schema
pidfile         /usr/local/var/run/slapd.pid
argsfile        /usr/local/var/run/slapd.args
database        bdb
suffix          "dc=eg,dc=com"
rootdn          "cn=manager,dc=eg,dc=com"
rootpw          secret
directory       /usr/local/var/openldap-data
index   objectClass     eq
```

it failed with prompt like this:

```
adding new entry "cn=config"
ldap_add: Insufficient access (50)
```

and when I created a ldif as shown in the guide

```
dn: dc=eg,dc=com 
objectclass: dcObject 
objectclass: organization 
o: Example Company 
dc: eg 

dn: cn=manager,dc=eg,dc=com 
objectclass: organizationalRole 
cn: manager
```

and try adding it as a new entry:

```
ldapadd -x -D "cn=manager,dc=eg,dc=com" -W -f example.ldif
```

it failed with prompt like this:

```
adding new entry "dc=eg,dc=com "
ldap_add: Invalid syntax (21)
additional info: objectclass: value #0 invalid per syntax
```

how to configure correctly to add a new entry?

is it possible that the [quick-start-guide](http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/quickstart.html) has been out-of-date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to reconfigure your server online when it has an offline configuration. You need to switch to the online configuration if you want to accomplish this sort of thing online, or else edit `slapd.conf` accordingly and restart OpenLDAP.

Off topic.